# How to insert a record by clicking on the link using AJAX in WordPress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am developing a plugin for WordPress.

### Looking for a solution

> I want to insert record (it may be any CRUD operation) when the user
>   click on the link `order-button`

I am very much new to Ajax so getting confused how to achieve when the user clicks on the Order link on the product grid it should be added to the custom table.

I have set up all bug not able to get link's data attribute in the Ajax callback function to pass it to the jQuery ajax method.

### Enqueue scripts

```
function gs_enqueue_ajax_scripts()
{
    wp_register_script('gs_ajax', GROUP_SHOP_ROOT . 'public/js/orders-ajax.js', ['jquery'], 1.0, true);
    wp_localize_script('gs_ajax', 'ajax_vars', [
        'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'nonce'    => wp_create_nonce('gs_nonce')
    ]);
    wp_enqueue_script('gs_ajax');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'gs_enqueue_ajax_scripts');
```

### Ajax actions and callback function

> I have tried passing static data and getting in the console output. Otherwise, it is giving null as it is not considering setting data directly into the AJAX data parameter.
>   **How can I get data dynamically in callback function from the clicked anchor tag?**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_gs_order', 'gs_ajax_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_gs_order', 'gs_ajax_callback');

function gs_ajax_callback()
{
    /**
     * I have set statically to check if it works
     * Of course, this is working since it is static
     * BUT I WANT DATA HERE DYNAMICALLY TO PASS IN AJAX
     */
    /*$data = [
        'product_groups' => 1,
        'products' => 5
    ];*/

    /*echo json_encode($data);*/

    // run the query to add entry
    /*$order = new Group_Shop_Order();
    $order->create_order(194, $products_ids, $product_groups_ids);*/

    wp_die();
}
```

### HTML - Product Grid Item

```
<li class="gs-p-item">
    <div class="gs-p-item-container">
        <p class="gs-p-name">
            <a href="http://to-product-page" title="Id adipisci dolores dicta">Id adipisci dolores dicta</a>
        </p>
        <p class="gs-p-price">38.90</p>
        <a class="gs-button order-button et_pb_button" data-pid="168" href="javascript:void(0)" id="gs-p-168">Order</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

### Javascript

> data parameter is returning `null` value

```
var $button = $('.order-button');
console.log(ajax_vars);
$button.attr('href', 'javascript:void(0)');

$button.on('click', function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajax_vars.ajax_url,
        data: {
            action: 'gs_order',
            nonce_data: ajax_vars.nonce,
            product_groups: $(this).data("pgid"),
            products: $(this).data("pid")
        },
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#response').html(data);
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            $('#response').html(data);
            console.log("Error is there"); //error
        }
    }); // ajax end

}); // on button click
```

### Console output

```
Object
    ajax_url: "http://wpdev.org/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"
    nonce: "34cb70d514"
    __proto__: Object


null
```

Comment: Please Add your DYNAMICALLY Data Code in your Question. return Some data after insert code.

Comment: There is not dynamic data yet in the function. This is exactly I want to know without form tag how can I get value.

Comment: You have not define `data-pgid` in anchor tag for `product_groups: $(this).data("pgid")`

Comment: @VaibhaviSojitra there are two types of products in markup only difference is `data("pid")` and `data("pgid")`

Comment: did you try by return `echo json_encode($somedata);` before `wp_die();` ??

Comment: @VaibhaviSojitra yes echo `json_encode($data)` is working fine. What my issue is not able to figure out how I can dynamically get data from the clicked link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198920/discussion-between-vaibhavi-sojitra-and-code-lover).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
 <div class="gs-p-item-container">
            <p class="gs-p-name">
                <a href="http://to-product-page" title="Id adipisci dolores dicta">Id adipisci dolores dicta</a>
            </p>
            <a class="gs-button order-button et_pb_button" data-pid="168" data-pgid="0" href="javascript:void(0)" id="gs-p-168">Order</a>

            <p class="gs-p-price">38.90</p>
            <a class="gs-button order-button et_pb_button" data-pid="168" data-pgid="0" href="javascript:void(0)" id="gs-p-168">Order</a>
        </div>
```

AJAX CALL

```
 var $ = jQuery;
var $button = $('.order-button');
$button.attr('href', 'javascript:void(0)');

$button.on('click', function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        data: {
            action: 'gs_order',
            product_groups: $(this).data("pgid"),
            products: $(this).data("pid")
        },
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#response').html(data);
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            $('#response').html(data);
            console.log("Error is there"); //error
        }
    }); // ajax end

}); // on button click
```

Function Code

```
    function gs_ajax_callback()
{
    // print_r($_POST);

    $data = [
        'product_groups' => $_POST['product_groups'],
        'products' => $_POST['products']
    ];

    echo json_encode($data);


    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: Appreciate for your help on chat.